# How to ensure my device never powers down when using two batteries (Hot swapping batteries)?

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, battery-charging, embedded

I have a device I am powering using two batteries. My constraint is that I can never let the device power down. For instance, I have multiple cameras that needs to stay on 24/7 but their isn't a battery that can last that long, therefore my goal is cascade multiple batteries and be able to swap them out without powering down the device.

My current solution is to use two batteries in parallel, one with a higher voltage (Power source 2, 14V) than the other one (Power source 1, 12V). When I need to swap my main power source (Power source 2), **would the second battery keep the device running?**

In other words, Power source 1 should power the device during the swap. Then, when power source 2 is reconnected, it should power the device, and at the same time recharge power source 1.

[image]

Batteries I am thinking of:

**Power source 1**: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00BWW9WRM/ref=ox_sc_sfl_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A17M1OH9UAKGE7

**Power source 2**: 
https://hobbyking.com/en_us/multistar-high-capacity-4s-20000mah-multi-rotor-lipo-pack.html?___store=en_us

Comment: "Please see the Diagram for a visualisation!". To that I say: Please don't force people to leave this site and make a proper circuit diagram under the edit tab. Or just copy and paste the image here. We should **not** need to leave this site to be able to answer your question.

Comment: @Harry new users ***can't*** use the circuitlab tool or post images. You should ***not*** demands things if You dont have a clue about what you are asking. Instead, edit the photos in.

Comment: And dont downvote a perfectly good question.

Comment: *"Please see the Diagram for a visualisation!"* Nope.  Not gonna happen.  If you can't be bothered to present all the necessary information to your question so the volunteers here don't need to go chasing around for it, then there is no reason for us to bother either.  Closing since the question is unclear without a diagram.

Comment: @Passe: We don't downvote good questions, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: @Passerby I did not downvote the question, I only do that if the person asking the question has been told to do X, been given enough time to do X, checked that the person has been online and able to read X, failed to do X. If I would've not seen a diagram by the time I write this comment, then I would've downvoted. - Also, I said that he/she could "copy and paste the image", which he/she can. So I will demand things that are bare minimum. It's an actual human being asking the question, I imagine that they are more than capable to carry out my simple task to save time for hundreds of others.

Comment: No, they cannot copy paste the image. NEW USERS CANNOT UPLOAD IMAGES OR USE THE CIRCUIT LAB TOOL WHICH IS BUILT ON THE IMAGE UPLOAD TOOL. They did everything a new user without enough rep can do, they hosted the image elsewhere and linked it here. Then higher rep users review and edit the image in. That's how it works. It's a simple task like i asked you to do.

Comment: Thanks @Passerby for making it clear to others. If what they mentioned was an option, I would certainly have bothered!

Comment: @Passerby [That makes no sense](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). Sorry. Not sorry. Also, are you okay?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the kind of battery you are using.

If you are using lead acid batteries; this is all fine and will work the way you describe.

If you are using practically any other type of battery; you should not do this, the batteries could charge at unsafe rates. It would be safer to wire a "schottky power diode" in series with each battery so that they can both power the system but nether can charge the other. You would swap the batteries and charge them away from this system.

Comment: With this arrangement, whichever battery currently has the highest voltage will power the system; the others will be idle.  If two are equal, they may end up sharing the load.

Comment: Or use a charge controller circuit or IC.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. As I'm new to this, let me recap your solution, and please correct me if I got it wrong:

We'll go with the setup from the diagram. In such a case, the battery with the higher voltage would power the device, and the battery with the lower voltage would be idle. Then, if we remove the battery with the higher voltage, the other battery will take over. But for safety reasons, we should add a charge controller or a "schottky power diode"  between the two batteries. Can you give me a little bit more information why we need the charge controller/diode?

Answer (score 1):

As Bracken has described, a diode bridge would work. Especially with the main power supply being a higher voltage. Keep in mind that the current draw may be an issue so the swap may cause a brown out, so a capacitor after the bridge would be recommended. You would need to test.

A better solution, would be to use an integrated charge controller. This would handle the charging for the smaller battery, and allow pass through power. Once the main battery is removed, the smaller battery should kick in through the charger circuit.